# Function in DolphinDB similar to numpy.clip()

Tags: python, numpy, dolphindb

Function numpy.clip() is used to clip(limit) the values in an array. Given an interval, values outside the interval are clipped to the interval edges. For example, if an interval of [2, 6] is specified, values smaller than 2 become 2, and values larger than 6 become 6.

```
import numpy as np 
  
in_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ] 
print ("Input array:", in_array) 
  
out_array = np.clip(in_array, a_min = 2, a_max = 6) 
print ("Output array:", out_array)
```

Output:

```
Input array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Output array: [2 2 3 4 5 6 6 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `winsorize` may work, to some extent, if you can specify the percentages to cut on each side of the vector.

Or, you can use the user-defined function as follows with `iif`:

```
def clip(x,minValue,maxValue): iif(x>maxValue,maxValue,iif(x<minValue,minValue,x))
in = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ] 
clip(in,2,6)
```

Output:

```
offset  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0       2   2   3   4   5   6   6   6
```